Is it necessary to cancel timer created by Timer.publish, in SwiftUI?
I inherited a code that is creating SwiftUI timer as below, inside a view struct.
struct CustomButton: View    {
    ...
    private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    ...

And do not see any code to cancel the timer once the intended trigger is achieved and work is done.
But looking at the below guide I se that it is suggested to cancel the timer using timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
My question is how important is to cancel this timer, and I dont see any issues faced by the team till now but is this something that can cause any kind of issues? Or if the view gets released the timer will get released so this is not that important?
Reference: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/triggering-events-repeatedly-using-a-timer

If you don't need it after a few iterations, it's just a waste of CPU power.

Do you want to cancel it? e.g. do you want to add a "stop" button or something like that, allowing the user to cancel the timer? If you just want to leave it running for as long as the view is in the view hierarchy, then onReceive will cancel it once the view is removed from the view hierarchy.

Since I inherited the code, as a reviewer I see that the timer is used to enable the button interaction after certain duration. And my doubt was should I cancel the timer at that point. Or leaving it running is equally fine.
To add, the code I am working on does not have the code to canel it on onReceive,

I don't mean that you need to call cancel in onReceive. I mean onReceive automatically cancels the publisher for you when the view is removed from the view hierarchy.

let timer = Timer... is actually not a good practice with SwiftUI and you could end up with memory leaks since SwiftUI can recreate the View at any time and create multiple timers.
The "best" way to handle animations and such is with TimelineView
TimelineView(.periodic(from: startDate, by: 1)) { context in
     AnalogTimerView(date: context.date)
}

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/timelineview
But if you have to use Timer you should use it with onReceive so it gets destroyed appropriately.
 .onReceive(Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()) { output in
    print("Timer called")
}

If you can also move into async/await and start using Task as an alternative.
struct TimerSample: View {
    @State private var isDisabled: Bool = true
    var body: some View {
        Button("Hello World!") {
            
        }.disabled(isDisabled)
            .task(id: isDisabled) {
                guard isDisabled else {return}
                try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(2))
                isDisabled.toggle()
            }
    }
}

